# Facebook Unity SDK login via Safari View Controller

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-login, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-unity-sdk

I am using Facebook Unity SDK 7.2.2 and by default my application use login via browser behaviour. I tried to change default FBLoginKitManager behaviour to login via application, so I force switched login behaviour to Native, but still login via  browser. I actually logged in to Facebook in settings.

Code from FBUnityInterface.mm startLogin method:

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    login.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorNative;
  if (isPublishPermLogin) {
    [login logInWithPublishPermissions:permissions
                    fromViewController:nil
                               handler:loginHandler];
  } else {
    [login logInWithReadPermissions:permissions
                 fromViewController:nil
```

Answer (score 0):

This is by design due to the changes in iOS9.
See more here: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2015/10/29/Facebook-Login-iOS9/